# Entity Framework Core: How to get the Connection from the DbContext?

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying the new Entity Framework Core with MySQL Connector.

I can get a valid `DbContext` and write into the database so everything has been setup correctly.

I need to get the `Connection` from the `DbContext` because I have to test for it at application starting using a `connection.Open()` inside a `try` statement. If there is not a valid connection, the console app should try to start MySQL Server and retry.

How can I get the `Connection` from the `DbContext`?

Before EF6 by `context.Connection`. After EF6 by `context.Database.Connection`.

It seems the latest has been removed too from EFCore.

Comment: there is something like - `dbContext.Database.OpenConnection()` or `dbContext.Database.GetDbConnection()` in EF Core - would that be useful?

Comment: No, unfortunately not.  I can't see anything like context.Database.OpenConnection() or context.Database.GetConnection() method, otherwise I would have simply called them.

Comment: Not sure why you are not getting it; its showing up for me. may be a missing package? I'm having it inside an extension class named `RelationalDatabaseFacadeExtensions` under `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` namespace- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationaldatabasefacadeextensions

Comment: I saw it in the docs. But If I try to hardcode it and to comile what I get is: "error CS1061: 'DatabaseFacade' does not contain a definition for 'GetDbConnection' and no extension method 'GetDbConnection' accepting a first argument of type 'DatabaseFacade' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: whats the version you are using? I have `"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.1"` and in tools `"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"`

Comment: Dependencies:  "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.0.0", "MySql.Data.Core": "7.0.4-IR-191", "MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore": "7.0.4-IR-191".

Comment: Try installing this package - https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational/

Comment: Thanks. This fixed it!

Comment: Make sure to include the extensions, this was the problem for me. (using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Extensions;)

Answer (score 106, accepted):

The `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational` (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational/) package provides extension methods for this - you can use `dbContext.Database.OpenConnection()` or `dbContext.Database.GetDbConnection()` to get the `DbConnection` object.

*Note: if you have `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` installed then you don't have to explicitly install this package*

Comment: GetDbConnection() in 2.0

Comment: Make sure to include the extensions, this was the problem for me. (using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Extensions;)

Comment: @hurlbz is that package obsolete? Can't find it.

Comment: I struggled with finding this as well. Just add a `using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` statement. As long as you have Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer or Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational included in your nuget deps, you should then see the extension methods.

Comment: GetDbConnection() fails when called second time on Database. I am using 'using (var connection = _dbContext.Database.GetDbConnection()) {}' block to invoke some commands. connection is Open and Closed within the using block, but yet when I run the same method for the second time I get faulty connection (ConnectionString missing, some property exceptions. What's causing it? Any workaround to this .NET Core EF bug?

Comment: @Radek - are you trying it after the _using_ block closure?

Comment: @RadekStrugalski this might be relevant: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/7810

Answer (score 16):

You can do the following :

1. If you are using System.Data.SqlClient change it to Microsoft.Data.SqlCLient since the later library will accept excplicit casting from the object of the DBContext in both EntityFramework and EntityFrameWorkCore.
2. Create a command from the DBContext connection and Cast it to your SQLCommand by

```cs
using (SqlCommand cmd = (SqlCommand)database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand())
```

3. Check the connection state and open it if necessary.

```cs
if (cmd.Connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
{
    cmd.Connection.Open();
}
```

4. If there is a transaction in the DBContext add it to the command.

```cs
if (database.CurrentTransaction != null)
{
    cmd.Transaction = database.CurrentTransaction.GetDbTransaction();
}
```

By doing this you will avoid any problems can appear when using comands outside the context.