# C# replacing foreach

Tags: c#

I'm using a Webservice GET request to get some info about customers. I want to insert a record to the DB for each customer returned from the request .

I have this code for now :

```
            var container = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MarkedCampaigns>(json);
            string insertDB = "";
            foreach (var item in container.items)
            {
                insertDB += "INSERT INTO TABLE (CampaignId,CookieId,Url) values(" + item.CampaignId + "," + item.VisitorExternalId + "," + item.Url + ");";
            }
            //EXECUTE STRING .
```

Container is the response from the Get request. It contains an Item property which each item represent a customer.

My question is, is this the correct way to insert the records to my DB? Or is there a simpler way using the container and some methods I'm not familiar with ?

Comment: Obligatory: [Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: Dont string up sql like that, use parameterised queries. You are asking for sql injections...

Comment: What @Sayse is trying to convey is that you're using unsafe practises regarding SQL injections. Look up "Preventing SQL injections" or similar :)

Comment: Not only unsafe practices, but practices that lead to wrongly declared string values. Your code would translate to `values(12, 31, https://www.google.com)` Do note the missing `'` in the URL

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are good ways to prevent SQL injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376473/what-are-good-ways-to-prevent-sql-injection)

Comment: How many elements are retrieved by that json? If you have few elements than you could write a loop as explained in the answer below and updated each element. If you have many elements then you should look at some kind of ORM that do the dirty work for you in a performant way

Comment: Whatever solution you choose, I would suggest testing it with a list of 2500 items. Some techniques will not handle that well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A part from the great problem of Sql Injection you are facing a decision to take. If you have few elements to insert then probably you could use a simple loop as explained in the answer from @derpisher, but that answer requires a call to the database engine for each element of your query and you need to define yourself all the parameters.

A single command text with many inserts is preferable because you make a single call to the database engine and in case of many records to insert the difference is noticeable. But this last approach is difficult if you want to use a parameterized query because you will need a parameter for each single value you want to insert.

Instead I suggest you to try using [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper).

With this simple ORM library you could write this

```
using(IDbConnection cnn = GetSqlConnection())
{
    string cmdText = @"INSERT INTO TABLE (CampaignId,CookieId,Url)
                       VALUES(@CampaignId, @VisitorExternalId, @Url)";
    cnn.Execute(cmdText, container.items);
}
```

Here the GetSqlConnection is a method that returns an instance of your connection already opened. The cmdText is the command to execute as if you have just one record to insert. The trick is the Execute extension command added by Dapper where you pass directly your list of items to insert and the commandtext. You only need to have the names of your parameters matching the names of the properties inside the list.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for when I posted this question. Thank you.

Comment: A question - "GetSqlConnection returns an instance of your connection" - how does it know my connection? Will it use me EF Core connection? Or how can I pass the connection string to it ? Sorry if this is a dumb question .

Comment: EF Core, I see it now, well that was not expected. You could look at this answer about getting the EF Core connection https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41935752/entity-framework-core-how-to-get-the-connection-from-the-dbcontext  and another interesting article about integrating Dapper in NET Core http://www.talkingdotnet.com/use-dapper-orm-with-asp-net-core/

Comment: _GetSqlConnection_ is not part of Dapper. It is just a simplification I have added here to expain the concept. You write that method inside your classes or use the suggested method to extract the instance of your connection

Comment: Oh I understand. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 2):

I would strongly suggest to use a prepared statement. This will on the one hand remove some unnecessary overhead for parsing the query every time and on the other hand it will force you to use parameterized queries, which will prevent issues with type conversion -- which I see will happen in your code because `url` is most likely some character type and you didn't add quotes -- and SQL injection.

```
string query = "INSERT INTO table(CampaignId, CookieId, Url) VALUES (@campaignid, @cookieid, @url)";

using (SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection(connectstring)) {
    c.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, c);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@campaignid", SqlDbType.Int, 0)); //use appropriate type/size here
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@cookieid", SqlDbType.Int, 0)); //use appropriate type/size here
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@url", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 500)); //use appropriate type/size here

    cmd.Prepare();

    foreach (var item in container.items) {
        cmd.Parameters[0].value = item.CampaignId;
        cmd.Parameters[1].value = item.VisitorExternalId;
        cmd.Parameters[2].value = item.url;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: Plus the prepared statements/parametrized queries have usually better performance.

Comment: @bradbury9 That's what I meant with "remove some unnecessary overhead ..."

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to do one call to the db to do all inserts then one option is to use a stored proc that takes a list:

The sql to create the type that will store our list:

```
create type [dbo].CampaignList as table (CampaignId int,  CookieId int, [Url] varchar(255))
```

The stored proc to do the inserts

```
create procedure [dbo].[spSaveCampaigns]
    @CampaignList CampaignList readonly
as
    insert into tblCampaigns (CampaignId, CookieId, [Url])
    select CampaignId, CookieId, [Url] from @CampaignList;
```

The C# to call it:

```
public async Task InsertCampigns()
        {
            var campaigns = new List<Campaign> {new Campaign(1, 1, "bar"), new Campaign(2, 2, "foo") };
            using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
            {
                using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("exec [dbo].[spSaveCampaigns] @CampaignList", sqlConnection))
                {
                    await sqlConnection.OpenAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

                    using (var table = new DataTable())
                    {
                        table.Columns.Add("CampaignId", typeof(int));
                        table.Columns.Add("CookieId", typeof(int));
                        table.Columns.Add("Url", typeof(string));

                        foreach (var campaign in campaigns)
                            table.Rows.Add(campaign.CampaignId, campaign.CookieId, $"{campaign.Url}");

                        var parameters = new SqlParameter("@CampaignList", SqlDbType.Structured)
                                         {
                                             TypeName = "dbo.CampaignList",
                                             Value = table
                                         };

                        cmd.Parameters.Add(parameters);
                        await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

You could pull the code that creates the data table from your type out to a helper to make this smaller.

Advantages:
It's parameterised properly.
I prefer to call stored procs rather than run sql against the db (but you might have a different opinion on this.)

Result calling

```
await InsertCampigns();
```

CampaignId | CookieId | Url

1   | 1 | bar

2   | 2 | foo

To do this without the stored proc, see this link from @Magnus in comment

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/table-valued-parameters#passing-a-table-valued-parameter-to-a-parameterized-sql-statement

Comment: It is a good idea to use table parameter if the list contains a lot of entries. Another option would be to use SqlBulkCopy. Also you dont need to create a stored procedure for this.

Comment: @Magnus How would you do it without the stored proc? Can you pass a table parameter just as any parameter to insert blah select from tableparam ? (I'm not a sql guy)

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/table-valued-parameters#passing-a-table-valued-parameter-to-a-parameterized-sql-statement